# Fastest way to flip the sign of some elements of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array `a` of doubles of dimension d (which is a power of 2, let's say between 64 and 1024).
Now I want to flip with probability 1/2 the sign of each element (and memorize the positions that have been flipped!).

What I do now is that I generate a second array of doubles `b` with only 1 and -1, and then:

```
for (int i=0; i<d; i++) a[i] = a[i]*b[i];
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do that. We technically need only 1 bit to memorize 1/-1, and I guess we can avoid the multiplication… but I'm not sure what is the best way to do that.

I tried the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<d; i++){
    if (b[i]<0)
        a[i]=-a[i];
}
```

to avoid the multiplication, but this is not faster (even slightly slower, actually).

Comment: There's [`copysign()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.11.1), though it might end up being slower than your multiplication-in-a-loop, which I'd imagine is a prime target for SIMD optimization.

Comment: While storing the signs in individual bits might be more memory-efficient, it will probably result in a worse runtime because the individual bits might be harder to address in memory. On the other hand, a batch of signs could be loaded into a register and the signs could be 'shifted out' and used for branching.

Comment: The comment of Ilja Everilä is very helpful; are you able to explicitly use SIMD macros for the multiplication or do you need plain C? For SIMD, the arrays would also have to be aligned to even memory addresses; what architecture do you target?

Comment: Between representing the signs via an array of doubles and representing them as a bit vector, there is representing them as an array of `signed char`.  This will be much more compact than the former form, for better cache usage, and the information will require fewer operations to extract than the latter form.  As with most performance questions, however, you ultimately need to *test* to determine what approach is fastest for you.

Comment: As long as the platform that you are running this on has hardware floating point support, like any PC, then doing a floating point operation is very fast. One issue with your second example is that if the `b[]` is still a floating point array, then you have a floating point operation in order to do the comparison and then half the time another floating point operation to change the sign.

Comment: Thank you for copysign(), I didn't know about it. Performances are very similar. I can use SIMD macro, but if the compiler already does the conversion automatically, I guess the result will be quite similar? And for the second version, I thought that maybe doing -a[i] did not require a floating point operation, but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: How about using 2's complement `a=~a+1` ? Is this faster.

Comment: Detail:  can the "flipped" sign of +0.0 be +0.0 or -0.0 (IOW the sign of 0.0 is irrelevant) or does code requirements mean that a flipped 0.0 must have it sign flipped?

Comment: The sign of 0 is not important (but anyway there are probably no zeros in the array). Does that change something?

Comment: On x86-64, the fastest way is to put `-0.0` (for *do negate*) and `+0.0` (for *do not negate*) into `b`, and then use either `_mm_xor_pd()` (any x86-64 variant) or `_mm256_xor_si256()` (if AVX2 is supported) to exclusive-OR `a` with `b`. (You also need to use for example `_mm_alloc(size, 32)` to allocate them instead of `malloc()`, since these special vector types need extra alignment.) You can get well under a cycle per double in the array (negated or not) for short arrays; to about a cycle per double for longer ones.